# Activating custom ITool from form without adding it to ArcMap AddIn toolbar?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, c#, tools, toolbar

I'm working on an add-in for ArcMap 10.0 that adds a toolbar to ArcMap. One command (`OpenModelessDialogCommand`) button on that toolbar opens a modeless WinForms dialog, from which a tool (`MyTool`) can be activated in order to e.g. select a feature on the map.

My `Config.esriaddinx` contains these command and toolbar declarations:

```xml
<Commands>
  <!-- this is the command that opens the modeless WinForms form, from where
       MyTool is available: -->
  <Button id="OpenModelessFormCommand" ... />
  <!-- MyTool is not directly referenced in any toolbar defined in this file: -->
  <Tool id="MyTool" class="MyTool" ... />
</Commands>
<Toolbars>
  <Toolbar ...>
    <Items>
      <Button refID="OpenModelessFormCommand" />
    </Items>
  </Toolbar>
</Toolbars>
```

What I'm having problems with is activating `MyTool` in the form. All I've found on the internet is code samples along the lines of:

```
// get a reference to an instance of MyTool:
ICommandItem myTool = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find("MyTool");
 // activate MyTool: 
ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = myTool;
```

However, this apparently requires that `MyTool` actually appears in a command bar (e.g. toolbar) of my add-in. But that's not the case. So, I've tried this next:

```
ITool myTool = new MyTool();
ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = myTool;  // Type mismatch! An ICommandItem is expected.
```

I've even looked into adding an invisible `AxToolbarControl` to my form and adding a button for `MyTool` there; but then I'm running into problems on how to connect that toolbar (via `SetBuddyControl`) to the opened document's map. I don't want the tool to function in a separate `AxMapControl`, I want it to work directly with the main map shown in ArcMap.

**Question:**
How do I activate a custom tool that is not added to any toolbar (or other command bar, for that matter)?

Comment: If you think my answer would work for you if commandbar worked as advertised, perhaps add a "bug" tag to your question.  Dirty laundry shown in public is often good motivation for a vendor to fix a bug.

Comment: @Kirk, I was going to do that, but I can't -- I haven't got enough rank here to create new tags, and `bug` doesn't seem to exist yet; please feel free to edit the tags yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me using ArcGIS 10 SP1. My custom tool is not on a toolbar:

```
    Dim UIDCls As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass()
    ' id property of menu from Config.esriaddinx document
    UIDCls.Value = "ClassLibraryAddin_MyTool"
    Dim document As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IDocument = My.ArcMap.Document
    Dim commandItem As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem = TryCast(document.CommandBars.Find(UIDCls), ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem)
    If commandItem Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    My.ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = commandItem
```

Comment: +1 If this works, this sure is simpler than the answer I posted.  I'm pretty sure I tried that but have since installed SP1, so maybe that was a factor.

Comment: The answer of lbross helped me a lot. Later I found almost the same solution in the ArcGis snippet finder: 'Statements - Use a Tool in a Windows Form.snippet' (I am using C#) I can't vote the answer up because I have too less reputation.

Comment: I cannot vote or add comments because I don´t have enough reputation, but lbross´s answer works for me in ArcGIS 10.2. I created a ITool without a toolbar and called it from a Windows button Víctor

Answer (score 3):

<del>I've never tried this, but seems like it should work:  In your modeless form have two member variables, the first (m_Tool) referencing your ITool and the second (m_Application) referencing the IApplication. In the constructor for your modeless form, have it instantiate the ITool and call [OnCreate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnCreate_Method/00430000002n000000/), passing an IApplication reference.</del>

On your modeless form have a button that, when clicked sets m_Application.[CurrentTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/CurrentTool_Property/002300000037000000/) = m_Tool.

Also, instead of doing a modeless dialog, I'd recommend using a dockable window perhaps using [using WPF within it](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=C93F0C29-1422-2418-88B6-4BCCD92FC2AF).

**Update**
In an attempt to atone for posting this lame answer, I've tried to hack something together.  It seems like you should be able to dynamically create a toolbar, hide it, add the tool to it (getting an ICommandItem to set to CurrentTool), then delete the toolbar without the user ever knowing the tool was on a toolbar.  However, ICommandBar.Dock and ICommandItem.Delete don't seem to work for dynamic toobars. IMHO this is a bug.

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    UID uid = new UIDClass();
    uid.Value = "Microsoft_ArcMapAddin1_Tool1";
    var bar = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Create("mybar", esriCmdBarType.esriCmdBarTypeToolbar)
        as ICommandBar;

    // bug, dock doesn't work ...
    bar.Dock(esriDockFlags.esriDockHide);
    bar.Add(uid);

    var itm = bar.Find(uid);
    if (itm != null)
    {
        ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = itm;
        // bug, delete doesn't work either
        ((ICommandItem)bar).Delete(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work, since CurrentTool property expects an ICommandItem. ICommandItem references cannot be created directly, but can only be retrieved through ICommandBars.

Comment: Quite right about currenttool, but ICommandbar.Add creates an ICommandItem from a UID.  Problem then becomes how to get rid of the commandbar after it is no longer needed (or at least hiding it).

Comment: wow, thanks for adding a working code example in your update. It's a shame that neither `Dock` nor `Delete` work, but it's a good start. I'll look into the `Delete` issue further, I think.

Comment: what an interesting idea, I'll definitely try to elaborate from that. Btw I also believe the behavior you describe is a bug.

Comment: I ended up using a different solution (among other things, by making my tool a Singleton so that I can easily get a reference to it; the `CommandBars.Find` problem suddenly solved itself, for some unknown reason), but I'm giving this answer the tick mark because this is probably what I would have done.

Comment: FYI - I found that if I showed the commandbar before hiding it, hiding worked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why do you need to add the tool in a toolbar. Because, I have worked with some similar thing and I haven't find any need to add it in the tool bar.

In my case, when user clicks on a button in the dockable window, a tool activates. To perform this work, my tool class looks like following:

- My tool id is:"ArcMap_SelectionTool"
- My tool class name is: "SelectionTool"
- Keep a static field of tool type in the tool class

  ```
  private static ICommandItem _selectionTool;
  private static SelectionTool _instance;
  public static SelectionTool Instance
  {
      get
      {
          if (_instance == null)
          {
              var selectionToolUID = new UID();
              selectionToolUID.Value = "ArcMap_SelectionTool";
              _selectionTool = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(selectionToolUID, false, false);
              if (_selectionTool == null)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Selection tool is not found.");
                  return null;
              }
          }
          if (_selectionTool != null)
              ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = _selectionTool;
          return _instance;
      }
  }

  public static void ExitToolInstance()
  {
      if (_instance != null)
          ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;
  }

  public SelectionTool()
  {
      _instance = this;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs arg)
  {
      if (arg.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
          return;
      //Do Work
  }
  ```

So, whenever I need to instantiate this tool, I call it in the following way:

```
        var toolInstance = SelectionTool.Instance;
```

After working with the tool, I need to exit tool instance. So I call `SelectionTool.ExitToolInstance()` method.

This procedure works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this by making the command (OpenModelessDialogCommand in your case) also a  tool (`ITool`). Upon clicking the command, I open up the form. Then I can also activate it as a tool at any moment.

If the tool you want to activate is not your own, you can relay calls from your ITool (implemented as above) to the other tool instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the map object, many tools can be runned by making a call to onCreate sending in for example the MapControl object to hook it up to the map. After that it's only to run the onClick method.

```
tool.OnCreate(control.Object)
tool.OnClick()
```

Don't work on all ESRI tools because some need to added to a toolbar.

Comment: How would I get a reference to such a map object? All I can ever seem to get is an `IMap` interface through `IMxDocument`, but clearly that's not the same, is it?

Comment: Edit: in Desktop it's the IApplication that is the hook object: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_commands_and_tools/000100000066000000/

Comment: sorry, I tried this; it doesn't work. The problem here is that the tool gets created, but is never activated. Second, I still don't see how I could get a `MapControl` object (if I actually need one at all) through `IApplication` or any object reachable from there.

Comment: You should pass in IApplication to OnCreate when doing this in Desktop, if I'm not misreading the documentation. Sending in a MapControl object works for me in Engine.

Comment: it seems correct that you would pass an `IApplication` object to `OnCreate` -- but that does not suffice (at least not for my custom tool), because the tool does not get activated by `OnCreate`, and will therefore not receive any input events.