# Listening for Map Click in ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, events

I have a seemingly simple requirement that is causing me all types of headaches - listening for a map click event in ArcMap via ArcObjects.  Simple as that, just tell me when the map is clicked (and x,y location obviously).

After some research, it appears that creating a custom tool that implements ITool was the way to go.  Well it turns out that approach gets ugly due to some 'bugs' in ArcGIS Desktop (v10 at least).  I don't want to add my custom tool to a toolbar, as it doesn't do anything and is irrelevant for a traditional ArcMap user.  So, I thought I would just create a 'hidden' toolbar containing my custom tool.  Well it turns out hiding a toolbar doesn't work so well (see [Activating custom ITool from form without adding it to ArcMap AddIn toolbar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7100)).

The only other thing I can think of to do is add my custom tool to a 'standard' toolbar.  The problem with this approach is that if the user then hides or removes whatever standard toolbar I put the custom tool in from ArcMap, the tool is no longer accessible.

Can someone tell me how to listen for a map click event without all the aforementioned complications?

Comment: If you want to listen out for map events in arcmap I think the way to do it is to create an extension and use that to get a handle on the events.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For me in 9.3.1, this is working. Registering to the appropriate event...

```
((ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.AxMapControl)PlanetBase.MapControlComponent).OnMouseDown += new ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.IMapControlEvents2_Ax_OnMouseDownEventHandler(Class1_OnMouseDown);
```

...and going on with...

```
void Class1_OnMouseDown(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.IMapControlEvents2_OnMouseDownEvent e)
    {
        //...
    }
```

I just checked, it works in ESRI 10 also...

Comment: Looks like your code is for ArcEngine; I am looking for ArcMap equivalent.