# Using ArcObjects control commands without ToolbarControl

Tags: arcobjects

I want to use some ArcObjects predefined commands for my buttons actions..I used this code

```
`ICommand command = new ControlsSceneZoomInToolClass();
            command.OnCreate(axMapControl1.Object);

        axMapControl1.CurrentTool = (ITool)command;`
```

when I press button the muse chenges to zoom in but it doesn't work..Is there some thing wrong with my code?

Comment: I found the solution here..For people that have my problem too
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/how-do-i-activate-a-custom-itool-from-a-form-without-having-to-add-it-to-a-toolb