# Activate / Deactivate customized ITool from Form in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vb

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3/VB6, and I have a little issue with the activation of a custom Tool:

I have a Class, that implements both `ICommand` and `ITool`

When I click on `ICommand`, the form is launched
First, The CurrentTool is deactivated

```
Set Application.CurrentTool = Nothing
```

Then I need to activate the `ITool`, so I click on a button, I get my tool UID, and :

```
Dim pSelectedTool As ICommandItem
Dim pCommandBars As ICommandBars
Dim pApp As IApplication

Set pCommandBars = pApp.Document.CommandBars
Set pSelectedTool = pCommandBars.Find(pUID)
Set pApp.CurrentTool = pSelectedTool
```

The `pApp.CurrentTool.Name` contain the name of my `ITool`, but the problem is that the Tool is still deactivated, when I click on the Map nothing happen!

I found a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/how-do-i-activate-a-custom-itool-from-a-form-without-having-to-add-it-to-a-toolb) similar to mine, but with no help.

Comment: Did you try calling `ICommand.OnClick` too?

Comment: Its called automatically when I click on the button on the Bar

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8513/59

Comment: Its the link I posted above :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, All I had to do is to refresh the Tool:

```
pApp.CurrentTool.Refresh
```